# Computed state not changing in reload page when function modifies state

Tags: vuejs3, vue-router, vue-composition-api, pinia

If I go to /notifications request is made and retrieves data, but when useStore().retrieveNotificationList() is called, doesn't change notifications state. But if I go to another page and click to notifications router-link it does. Any idea?

Routes befores

```
router.beforeResolve((to, from, next) => {
  if (!isLoggedIn) {
    useAuthStore().refreshAccessToken()
    .then(() => next() )
  } else {
    next()
  }
})

router.beforeEach(async (to, from, next) => {
    if(to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresLogin && !isLoggedIn)){
        next({name: 'login'})
    } else{
        next()
    }
})
```

Store

```
export const useStore = defineStore('core', {
    state: () => {
        return {
            notifications: null
        }
    },
    actions: {
        retrieveNotificationList() {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                getAPI.get('/api/notifications/')
                .then(response => {
                    this.notifications = response.data
                    resolve()
                })
                .catch(err=> console.error(err))
            })
        },
        deleteNotification(id) {
            getAPI.delete('/api/notifications/' + id)
                .then(() => this.notifications = this.notifications.filter(item => item.id !== id))
        }
    }
})
```

NotificationsView

```
<template>
        <router-link to="/">Home</router-link> |
    <div :class="{'read':notification.read}" v-for="notification in notifications" :key="notification.id" class="notification">
        <p>{{ notification.message }}</p>
        <button @click="deleteNotification(notification.id)">X</button>
    </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { useStore } from '../store/index'
import { computed } from 'vue'

useStore().retrieveNotificationList()

const notifications = computed(() => {
    return useStore().notifications
})

function deleteNotification(id) {
    useStore().deleteNotification(id)
}
</script>
```

Comment: You're missing an **await** before useStore().retrieveNotificationList(). When used like that, as a top-level await, it will automatically compile your `<script setup>` code as async setup().